# New to SQL - Organization and Optimization of Queries

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, query-optimization, database-connection

For a thick-client project I'm working on, I have to remotely connect to a database (IBM i-series) and perfom a number of SQL related tasks:

1. `Download/Update a set of local/offline 'control' data` - this data may have changed between runs unnoticed.
2. `On command, download data from multiple (15-20) tables and store separately into a single Java object.`  The names of the tables are known, but the schema name changes between runs and can change inter-run (as far as I know, `PreparedStatements` do not allow one to dynamically insert the schema).
   I had considered using joins/unions/etc to perform all of these queries as one, but the project requires me to have in-memory separations between table data (instead of one big joined lump).
3. `Perform between 2 and 100+ repetitions of (2)`

The last factor is that this needs to be run on high-latency (potentially dial-up) network connections using Java 1.5 on the oldest computers possible.

Currently I run 15-20 dynamically constructed `PreparedStatements` but I know this to be rather inefficient (I measured, so as to avoid premature optimization ala Knuth).

**What would be the most efficient and error-tolerant method of performing these tasks?**
My thoughts:

- Regarding `(1)`, I really have no idea other than checking the entire table against the new table, at which point I feel I might as well just download the new (potentially and likely unchanged) table and replace the old one, but this takes more time.
- For `(2)`: Ideally I'd be able to construct something similar to an array of `SELECT` statements, send them all at once, and have the database return one `ResultSet` per internal query.  From what I understand, however, neither `Statement` nor `PreparedStatement` support returning multiple `ResultSet` objects.
- Lastly, the best way I can think of doing `(3)` is to batch a number of `(2)` operations.

Comment: You may benefit from being able to run Java code on the IBM i too which can do this, and give you an object back e.g. through RMI.

Comment: Statement has the getMoreResults() method, which is used to read multiple result sets. (Unless you meant that your JDBC driver doesn't support it, which may be possible.)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen unfortunately I don't have access to the database(s) themselves (the client can connect to different DBs between runs - same general structure however), only access to Connection objects, etc.  If this is still possible, mind detailing a bit more of how to do so? :)

Comment: I do not think you can maintain Java-based stored procedures through SQL on DB2/400 (which Oracle can), so this is most likely not an option.

Comment: @NateC-K I am unclear how to return multiple `ResultSet` objects...Exceptions are thrown if I try to separate statements with a `;`.  I also get exceptions if I try to use the `addBatch()` command, as per the documentation: (from `executeBatch()`: **throws** `BatchUpdateException (a subclass of SQLException) if one of the commands sent to the database fails to execute properly or attempts to return a result set.`)

Comment: From what I gather online, that's a limitation of the DB2 JDBC drivers and you won't be able to get multiple result sets from a single query statement. Normally the way you get multiple result sets is by calling a stored procedure, but it looks like that's not an option for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about having moving requirements, but the single most important thing to use when talking to most databases is having a connection pool in your Java application and use it properly.

This also applies here.  The IBM i DB2/400 database is quite fast, and the database driver available in the jt400 project (type 4, no native code) is quite good, so you can pull over quite a bit of data in a short while simply by generating SQL on the fly.

Note that if you only have a single schema you can tell in the conneciton which one you need, and can then use non-qualified table names in your SQL statements.  Read the JDBC properties in the InfoCenter very carefully - it is a bit tricky to get right.  If you need multiple schemaes, the "naming=system" allows for library lists - i.e. a list of schemaes to look for the tables, which can be very useful when done correctly.  The IBM i folks can help you here.

That said, if the connection is the limiting factor, you might have a very strong case for running the "create object from tables" Java code directly on the IBM i.  You should already now prepare for being able to measure the traffic to the database - either with network monitoring tooling, using p6spy or simply going through a proxy (perhaps even a throtteling one)

Comment: I've gotten by so far by using ConnectionPooling and generating on the fly (one of the first optimizations, definitely one of the most important also).  Unfortunately, however, at least one `Connection` must be created before the majority of the Schemas used are known (only one is known in the beginning, the schemas change depending on user and user's choice of operations).

Comment: Would you have a recommendation for a connection pool for Java? (and a network monitor component?)  And again, while there is only one 'database group', they monitor 20+ databases and are very reluctant to make 'unnecessary' changes.  It may come down to butting heads, but if there are other options, I'd rather explore those.

Comment: I would suggest opening a new question for each thing you want to know.

Comment: Thanks - I can go do research instead of asking others to google it lol :)

Comment: No. Stackoverflow is not intended for extra questions in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would have the database group provide you with a set of stored procedures to optimize the access to the database.

Since you don't have access, you may want to ask them if they have timestamp data in the database at the row level to see when records were modified, this way you can select only the data that's changed since some point in time.

What @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen is suggesting is moving the database code on to the IBM host and connecting to it via RMI or JMS from the client.  So the server code would be a RMI or JMS Server that accesses the database on your behalf and returns you java objects instead of bringing SQL resultsets across the wire.

I would pass along your requirements to the database team and see if they can't do something for you.  I'm sure they don't want all these remote clients bringing all the data down each time, so it would benefit them as much as it would benefit you.

Comment: Sadly, while there is only one database group, there are 20+ databases, and changes are extremely frowned upon.  A last resort, perhaps, but only if nothing else works :(